# Is there a way I can use (copies of) classes in android studio, that once got deprecated and then deleted?

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

I haven't found an answer to my question anywhere on google/stackoverflow and thought many others would want to know the same thing.
My question is not, if deprecated classes/methods can be used in android studio.
I want to know if there is a way how I can use such classes/methods, even after they have been deleted from the android libraries.

I have for example created my own system keyboard which requires the **Keyboard** class, which is deprecated since API 29.
If that class once gets deleted, can I just find a copy of it somewhere, and copy/import it into my project? Is that the easiest way to do it?
Or do I just have to change things about the SdkVersions in the .gradle file?

Any help is appreciated.
-kuyaC

Comment: The open source nature of android means that you can peek through the older SDK code yourself, extract that particular class and rebuild it yourself even though it may also have some deprecated dependencies. Note that this is in no way advisable because most of the times, deprecated classes and methods are replaced with better ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If that class once gets deleted

That class is unlikely to be deleted. If it were, it would break any existing input method editors that depend upon it.

> can I just find a copy of it somewhere, and copy/import it into my project?

I would not use the word "just" in that sentence. :-)

You can get the source to `Keyboard` easily enough — [here is the one from Android Q Beta 6](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-q-preview-6/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java). However, it is not going to compile for you, as it will depend on a lot of internal classes and resources that are not part of the Android SDK.

So, while you could use it as inspiration for creating your own replacement, it is unlikely to be usable directly.